# $_POST and submit button

Tags: php, html

My HTML code:

```
<p>NEWS</p>
<p>
    <form action="news.php" method="post"> <center><input name="NEW" type="submit"
    id="new" value="NEW"/>
        <input name="Modify" type="submit" id="Modify2" value="Modify" />
    </form>
</p>
```

**news.php**

```
<?php  //Main function
    $event=$_POST;
    if($event=='NEW')
        post_new(); //already defined   
    else if($event=='Modify')
        modify();//already defined
?>
```

`post_new()` and `Modify()` are already defined in the document.

What I intend to do is check which button has been clicked on the first page and invoke the functions accordingly but I don't know where I am wrong because its not working. Please help, thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: "Not working" is not a good problem description. What exactly does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$event (and $_POST) is an array. Use it like this:

```
<?php  //Main function
    $event=$_POST;
    if(isset($event['NEW']))
         post_new(); //already defined   
    else if(isset($event['Modify']))
         modify();//already defined
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this you will have to check:

```
if($_POST['NEW']=="NEW")
  post_new();
else if($_POST['Modify']=="Modify")
  modify();
```

Comment: You should use isset() in your scripts to avoid notices.

Comment: @ping localhost.. well.. i had already tried using that but it says"Undefined index: NEW" when Modify button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Try `print_r($_POST)` to see the full contents and structure of $_POST (which is an array)